# How to detect when user leaves an EditText?

Tags: android

I want an EditText to lose focus the moment the user touches other UI elements in the Activity like check boxes or really touches anywhere outside the EditText within the Activity, but this is not happening.  The focus only gets changed when the user starts typing into another EditText.  Not for example when they click on an Checkbox or when they click on other areas of the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1?. If this doesn't help, can you make your question more specific?

Comment: Its not a duplicate.  This is a slightly different than keyboard question, although it does sound similar.  In this case the keyboard will go away when you take some other action, but the problem is the EditText does not lose focus.  Because it does not loose focus I cannot change the input method at the point I would like.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to add the following two lines to all of the widgets in your layout:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

That way they can all receive focus (normally only certain ones can) and you can attach `onFocusChangeListener` to the EditText in question and you should achieve the desired results.

Of course, this could also play havoc with your other widgets (not knowing what they are I can't be certain), but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score -1):

Could you not just force close the android soft keyboard on click event of another View?

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

The toggle call literally does just that - if its open, it will close, if its closed, it will open!

Comment: This is not about the keyboard.  But its similar. It really about how to detect make the EditText loose focus.  When the keyboard is gone the EditText still has the focus.

Comment: Say when keyboard shuts give something else a requestFocus call then?

Comment: How can I detech when keyboard shuts?

Comment: and know that it just detached from that EditBox?

Comment: Perhaps you are right that it is about the keyboard in a sense, but I need to know how to detect the close of the keyboard and know that it is closing from that particular EditText as there are others?  Please update your answer.

Comment: What I am trying to do is change the TransformationMethod at this point to obfuscate.  So I need a hook into this moment.